# Datatables - parameter 0 for fow 0

Tags: datatables

```
$('#datatable').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "../../WebPost/AjaxPinToFolderSearch",
                "data": function (d) {
                    d.postID = globalPinToFolderSearchID;
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "Folder", "defaultContent": "Value Not Received" },
                    { "data": "Pinned", "defaultContent": "Value Not Received" },
                    { "data": "StartDate", "defaultContent": "Value Not Received" },
                    { "data": "EndDate", "defaultContent": "Value Not Received" }
                ]
            }
        });
```

With example response (taken from developer tools Network Response):

```
{"data":[{"Folder":"Home/Test One/Frogger","Pinned":false,"StartDate":"\/Date(18000000)\/","EndDate":"\/Date(18000000)\/"}]}
```

Here is an example showing the error message:  http://lektrikpuke-001-site1.ctempurl.com/

Datatables appears to be working correctly in that it is requesting and receiving data. The error pops up, the table displays empty rows (responsive - 1 row of data = 1 row in table, 10 rows of data = 10 blank rows in table). I realize this is a common question, but I cannot figure out what is wrong. As a note, backend is C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor issue: The **columns** option shouldn't be a part of the **ajax** options. Move it out and it'll work without any errors as the DataTable now will receive the correct columns (which in your case was `null`). I tested it in the console and it worked. Let me know if that doesn't work for you.

Comment: No, didn't work.  I did change as suggested, even though the columns code was originally commented out, but no joy.  As a note, I copied the original code to About page as a reference.

Comment: Misunderstood your instructions.  It works now, thanks.  To be fair, the columns section was commented out, so columns are needed, just not in the ajax section (and I refer to the example from the link, not what I posted here).

Comment: My bad that I wasn't clear enough when I said "move it out". Anyway, glad it worked out. And yes, **columns** are needed as they're responsible to show the respective columns from the data. Here's the [official doc related to that error alert](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4).